# Tricky Go xml.Unmarshal() case

Tags: go, xml-parsing, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to unmarshal XML like this in Go:

```
<property>
  <code value="abc"/>
  <valueBoolean value="true"/>
</property>
```

or this

```
<property>
  <code value="abc"/>
  <valueString value="apple"/>
</property>
```

or this

```
<property>
  <code value="abc"/>
  <valueDecimal value="3.14159"/>
</property>
```

etc., into this:

```
type Property struct {
    Code  string      `xml:"code>value,attr"`
    Value interface{}
}
```

where the tag (`valueBoolean`, `valueString`, etc.) tells me what the type of the value attribute is. The XML that I'm trying to parse is part of [an international standard](http://hl7-fhir.github.io/), so I don't have any control over its definition. It wouldn't be hard to implement parsing these things, something like:

```
var value string
for a := range se.Attr {
    if a.Name.Local == "value" {
        value = a.Value
    } else {
        // Invalid attribute
    }
}
switch se.Name.Local {
case "code":
case "valueBoolean":
    property.Value = value == "true"
case "valueString":
    property.Value = value
case "valueInteger":
    property.Value, err = strconv.ParseInteger(value)
case "valueDecimal":
    property.Value, err = strconv.ParseFloat(value)
...
}
```

but I can't figure out how to tell the XML package to find it, and these things are buried in other XML that I'd really rather use `xml.Unmarshal` to handle. Alternately, I could redefine the type as:

```
type Property struct {
    Code         string `xml:"code>value,attr"`
    ValueBoolean bool   `xml:"valueBoolean>value,attr"`
    ValueString  string `xml:"valueString>value,attr"`
    ValueInteger int    `xml:"valueInteger>value,attr"`
    ValueDecimal float  `xml:"valueDecimal>value,attr"`
}
```

but that's pretty inefficient, particularly given that I'll have a large number of instances of these things, and this leaves me no way to derive the type without adding another attribute to indicate the type.

Can I somehow tie this into the normal XML unmarshalling method, just handling the tricky part by hand, or do I need to write the whole unmarshaller for this type from scratch?

Comment: I think writing a custom unmarshaler is pretty much the only way for it.

Comment: This is part of other XML whose definition is 10's of 1,000's of lines. Do I have to write an unmarshaler myself for the whole thing?

Comment: No, just for the property struct.

Comment: Ah, I see. If I add an Unmarshal method to the struct, it'll be called automagically by xml.Decoder.DecodeElement?

Comment: Yep, but keep in mind that you will have to also assign the Code member. If you figure it out, you should post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the pointer from OneOfOne, here's an implementation that works well with the standard XML unmarshaler:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Property struct {
    Code  string `xml:"code"`
    Value interface{}
}

const xmldata = `<properties>
  <property>
<code value="a"/>
<valueBoolean value="true"/>
  </property>
  <property>
<code value="b"/>
<valueString value="apple"/>
  </property>
  <property>
<code value="c"/>
<valueDecimal value="3.14159"/>
  </property>
</properties>
`

func (p *Property) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if start.Name.Local != "property" {
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid start tag for Property")
    }

    for {
        tok, err := d.Token()

        if tok == nil {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        switch se := tok.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            var value string
            var valueAssigned bool

            for _, attr := range se.Attr {
                if attr.Name.Local == "value" {
                    value = attr.Value
                    valueAssigned = true
                } else {
                    return fmt.Errorf("Invalid attribute %s", attr.Name.Local)
                }
            }

            if !valueAssigned {
                return fmt.Errorf("Valid attribute missing")
            }

            switch se.Name.Local {
            case "code":
                p.Code = value
            case "valueBoolean":
                if value == "true" {
                    p.Value = true
                } else if value == "false" {
                    p.Value = false
                } else {
                    return fmt.Errorf("Invalid string %s for Boolean value", value)
                }
            case "valueString", "valueCode", "valueUri":
                p.Value = value
            case "valueInteger":
                if ival, err := strconv.ParseInt(value, 10, 32); err != nil {
                    return err
                } else {
                    p.Value = ival
                }
            case "valueDecimal":
                if dval, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value, 64); err != nil {
                    return err
                } else {
                    p.Value = dval
                }
            default:
                return fmt.Errorf("Invalid tag %s for property", se.Name.Local)
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(xmldata)

    type Properties struct {
        List []Property `xml:"property"`
    }

    var properties Properties

    d := xml.NewDecoder(r)

    if err := d.Decode(&properties); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    for _, p := range properties.List {
        switch p.Value.(type) {
        case bool:
            if p.Value.(bool) {
                fmt.Println(p.Code, "is true")
            } else {
                fmt.Println(p.Code, "is false")
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println(p.Code, "=", p.Value)
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
a is true
b = apple
c = 3.14159
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! a minor nitpick, `xml:"code>value,attr"` isn't needed anymore so it can be safely removed.'

Comment: I didn't realize that! I'll fix it.